# How to get data in array from backend express js using mongodb cluster?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I have successfully fetch data from mongodb cluster and to check the data i have change it to json.stringify but i am unable to convert fetch data into array form.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Messages = () => {
  const [data,setData]=useState('');
  const getData = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/getmessage`);
    setData(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>Form21
{JSON.stringify(data)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Messages
```

Comment: The code looks good. What is the shape of data?

Comment: Can you post the result of `console.log(data)` after the `axios` call?

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
 const [data,setData]=useState('');
```

to

```
 const [data,setData]=useState([]);
```

it worked